# Element in struct not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

```
struct prediction
{
    int p1;
    int p2;
};

struct player
{
    vector <prediction> p;
    int score=0;
    string name;
};

int winner (player pla, prediction pred, int i)
{
    if (pla.p[i].p1 >= p.p1)
    {
        pla.p[i].score +=10;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error is in `pla.p[i].p1` winner function the error is p was not declared in this scope . I think

the problem is in the relation between struct `player` and `predection` .

Can anyone find the problem ?

Comment: What do you believe `p` refers to in `p.p1`?

Comment: You've misidentified where the error is.  The error message is about the `p.p1` after the `>=`, not the `pla.p[i].p1` before it.  The spaces before the semicolons and commas are generally considered undesirable, and the erratic indentation leaves much to be desired, too.

Comment: The problem lies on the other side of the operator. What is `p.p1` supposed to be? You have no variable `p` in scope.

Comment: yes i was wrong i wrote p but it's pred

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is p is meant to be pred as p is not declared in the function.

```
int winner (player pla, prediction pred, int i)
{
    if (pla.p[i].p1 >= pred.p1) //changed p to pred
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a mistake in your code.

> Structure is like a blueprint of some object. We may say how that
>   object will look like. For example we have a map of a building, that's
>   the way building is build. Can anyone live in the map of building? No,
>   because it is only map. Structure has same behavior. It is like a map
>   for an object. How that object will look like?, which variables will
>   it hold?, how much memory will it's object need. A structure itself
>   has no memory allocated but the Object of structure holds memory area
>   and can store things.

In your code, prediction and player has no memory but their objects i.e. pla, pred. So do not initialize your score variable in structure declaration. You may make some constructor for it. code will look like this.

```
struct player
  {
    vector <prediction> p ;
    int score ;
    string name ;

    player(){
      score = 0;
    }
  };
```

The other thing, You didn't quote where does p refer? This line makes no sense to me.

```
pla.p[i].score += 10;
```

I have structured a code for you but still have very poor idea about your logic.

```
struct prediction
{
    int p1;
    int p2;
};
struct player
{
    vector <prediction> p;
    int score;
    string name;

    player() {
        score = 0;
    }
};
int winner(player pla, prediction pred, int i)
{
    if (pla.p[i].p1 >= pred.p1)
    {
        pla.score += 10;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the quote from?

Comment: @M.Awais, int score=0; will do the same thing as the constructor. It's a C++11 and above feature.

Comment: @M.Awais The quote at the top about a structure being a blueprint.

Comment: May be. I have no idea. I'll try to learn about it today. Thanks for sharing. @DominicMcDonnell

Comment: I just went through it. You're right @DominicMcDonnell